# No matching template found when using single.php

Tags: posts, theme-development, single

I am building my own WordPress theme. I have the front page working. However, when I try to view a test post full of Lorem Ipsum, I get the "No matching template found" error.

I have the following code in single.php

```
<?php
    get_header();

    if( have_posts()){
        while( have_posts() ){
            the_post();
            the_content();
        }
    }

    get_footer();
?>
```

single.php is under directly my custom theme's root folder.

From what I understand, the page should just display the content, albeit without much styling. I navigated to the post using the "view post" link on the post edit page if that matters.

Just to be sure, I also placed the same code in page.php, index.php, and page.php

No success. No matter what I try, I still get "No matching template found" when navigating to the test post.

What am I missing here? Is there a way to troubleshoot the template hierarchy?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have an `index.php` file? Themes must have an `index.php` file to be valid, and that file acts as the final fallback at the end of the template hierarchy. What you're describing does not make sense in a valid theme. The absolute minimum required theme needs a `style.css` and an `index.php`, even if you do not intend to use those files they must be present. Likewise `single.php` must be at the top level of the theme it cannot be inside a subfolder

Comment: Additionally, the error message you mentioned only occurs when loading a block theme template part, there is more going on here than just files in a theme, did you try to use the site editor or declare that your theme is a block based theme?

Comment: I have an index.php file. The code mentioned above is present in it and I still get the error. Also, how do you declare a block based theme? I am not deliberately trying do build one.

Comment: do you have a `theme.json`? Or have set up a template for that post using the UI? It's possible to override the template of a single page and create a block based template

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not quite too sure what happened here, but I reset WordPress without changing the theme and that resolved the issue. If I figure out what setting it was that caused it, I will post it here.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, a WP core upgrade did not cleanly auto-install. To fix this part of the problem, I had to manually recreate the "themes" folder/directory, then reinstall my theme.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with the error message "No matching template found", be sure to check if the global `WP_CONTENT_DIR` is set correctly in your `wp-config.php` file.

I encountered this problem muliple times now. So I felt the urge to share this solution here.